# jQuery changing automatically divs

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I made a simple code for changing ***divs...*** 
But I thought it would be nice if it automatically toggle with some timeout.

A have created everything only the problem is i am not a js programmer.

The HTML A want to keep like now  if it possible.. I would change only js.
I think the js code is not well, but somehow must be start:)

HTML -- >

```
  <div class="container">
        <!-- helper class -->
        <div class="green-section hover push">
           <div class="col-md-3"></div>
           <!-- Text inner -->
           <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="text-inner">
                 <p class="text-centered web-description"><span class="webdesign">Work
                    great on all device <i class="icon-magic"></i></span> Lorem ipsum
                    dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
                    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                 </p>
                 <p class="text-centered app-description"><span class="appdev">Mobile
                    friendly <i class="icon-beaker"></i></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                 </p>
                 <p class="text-centered doc-description"><span class="doc">Detailed
                    documentation <i class="icon-info"></i></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
                    ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                 </p>
                 <p class="text-centered clean-description"><span class="clean">Clean
                    code <i class="icon-list-ul"></i></span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
                    consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                 </p>
              </div>
           </div>
           <!-- Text inner end -->
           <!-- helper class -->
           <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <!-- ||||| Welcome End ||||| -->
     <!-- ||||| Features ||||| -->
     <div class="container">
        <div class="features">
           <!-- first box -->
           <div class="col-md-3  padding-5 dark text-center btn1 hover"><i class="icon-3x icon-code"></i>
           </div>
           <!-- second box -->
           <div class="col-md-3  padding-5 dark text-center btn2 hover"><i class="icon-3x icon-copy"></i>
           </div>
           <!-- third box -->
           <div class="col-md-3  padding-5 dark text-center btn3 hover"><i class="icon-3x icon-mobile-phone"></i>
           </div>
           <!-- fourth Box -->
           <div class="col-md-3  padding-5 laptop-bg text-center  btn4 hover"><i class="icon-3x icon-laptop"></i>
           </div>
        </div>
        <!-- features end -->
     </div>
     <!-- container end -->
```

JS

```
$(".btn1").on("click", function () {
    $('.btn1').css("background-color", "#7fe5b2");
    $('.btn2,.btn3,.btn4').css("background-color", "#222222");
});
$(".btn2").on("click", function () {
    $('.btn2').css("background-color", "#7fe5b2");
    $('.btn3,.btn4,.btn1').css("background-color", "#222222");
});
$(".btn3").on("click", function () {
    $('.btn3').css("background-color", "#7fe5b2");
    $('.btn4,.btn2,.btn1').css("background-color", "#222222");
});
$(".btn4").on("click", function () {
    $('.btn4').css("background-color", "#7fe5b2");
    $('.btn3,.btn2,.btn1').css("background-color", "#222222");
});


$(".toggle-btn").on("click", function () {
    $('.green-section').css("background", "#222222");

});


$(".btn3").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".app-description").show();
    $(".web-description, .clean-description, .doc-description").hide();
});

$(".btn4").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".web-description").show();
    $(".app-description, .clean-description, .doc-description").hide();
});
$(".btn2").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".doc-description").show();
    $(".app-description, .clean-description, .web-description").hide();
});
$(".btn1").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".clean-description").show();
    $(".app-description, .web-description, .doc-description").hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7Aftr/)

Sorry for my english ... and thanks for any help guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your html at all, here's what I have:

```
// link the btns and the descriptions
$('.btn1').data('description', '.clean-description');
$('.btn2').data('description', '.doc-description');
$('.btn3').data('description', '.app-description');
$('.btn4').data('description', '.web-description');

// for each div in the .features section (btns) add a click event
$(".features div").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.features div').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.green-section .text-inner p').hide();
    $($(this).data('description')).show();
});

// Add a function to click the next btn in the .features section
function clickNext() {
    var divs = $('.features div.selected').next();
    if (divs.length) {
        divs[0].click();
    } else {
        $('.features div')[0].click();
    }
}

// add an interval to click the next btn every 4 seconds
setInterval(function () {
    clickNext();
}, 4000);
```

But, I would reccommend adding the data tags in the html and making sure that the green-section and the features section have ids.  That will make sure you are targeting the correct things with your jquery code.

http://jsfiddle.net/bhlaird/7bbDq/1/

Comment: Thanks Barbara... Working great :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add an interval to your javascript so that it can loop through them.
You may also want to change the way youre doing the colors. Try adding classes to them its much neater and easier to control

```
var selectedDiv = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(rotate,5000);
});


function rotate(){
console.log("ASDFASFD");
switch(selectedDiv)
{
    case 1:
      $(".btn2").click();
      break;
    case 2:
      $(".btn3").click();
      break;
    case 3:
      $(".btn4").click();
      break;
    case 4:
      $(".btn1").click();
      break;
}
}
```

Demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/7Aftr/1/

Answer (score 1):

add this at the end of js

```
autoToggle = function (no)
{
    $(".btn"+no).click();
    if(no == 4)
    {
       no=1; 
    }
    else
    {
         no++;   
    }
    setTimeout("autoToggle("+no+")",2000);
}
autoToggle(1);
```